# What is purpose of django.setup()?

Tags: python, django

I am updating website of my previous employee & have some issue with following code.

What is purpose of django.setup() line in following code.
Is it necessary to put below code in init.py file.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
import django
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "sparrow.settings")
django.setup()
```

Comment: To cite the documentation: [Calling django.setup() is required for “standalone” Django usage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage)

Comment: Thanks but what does it mean by standalone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is used if you run your Django app as standalone. It will load your settings and populate Django's application registry. You can read the detail on the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage).

As mentioned in the docs, `django.setup()` may only be called once. So, if you are facing an issue with the code, you could try modify the code into this:

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
import django
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app_name.settings")
if __name__ == '__main__':
   django.setup()
```

Comment: What does it mean by standalone ?

Comment: You run the component (Django app) independently

Comment: yes but problem here is that I am not running it here independently & above code part of my django website & included into init.py file of app.

Comment: Yes, and that's probably causing the issue. Therefore, I suggested you to modify the code to avoid calling `django.setup()` multiple times by call it under the if block.